# Passing ReportParameters back to method

Tags: c#, type-conversion, rdl

I have an application that is doing all of our reporting with locally stored RDLs. I have two forms, one is a simple viewer that contains a TabPageControl, and the other is an FLP of controls that the user can use to select report parameters. We are planning on having over 30+ options, but at the moment we only have around 5 (certain ones display for certain reports, the rest are hidden).

The issue I'm running into is that I need to have some way to get the options they chose out of a List or Collection. The method I'm using right now is

```
public void AddReportToViewer(string reportName, List<ReportParameter> parameterList = null)
    {
        TabPage newPage = new TabPage();      
        ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();

        newPage.Text = reportName;
        newPage.Controls.Add(reportViewer);

        tbcReports.TabPages.Add(newPage); //adding the report viewer to page, should do this at the end of the method

        reportViewer.Reset();
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "MyPath/reportName";
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();

        //parse parameters to individual objects to use with method calls

        int parameterEmployeeID = 0;
        int parameterStoreID = 0;
        List<int> parameterStoreIDs = null;
        DateTime parameterFromDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime parameterToDate = DateTime.Now;

        //Use parameters to get objects, just one here, but we have multiple

        List<EmployeeTimeclockReportObjects> timeclock = reportBL.getEmployeeTimeclock(parameterEmployeeID, parameterStoreID, parameterFromDate, parameterToDate);
        reportBindingSource.DataSource = timeclock;
        rds = new ReportDataSource("TimeclockEntries", reportBindingSource);
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

        reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        reportViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;            
    }
```

This all works, but here's where I need help

```
        int parameterEmployeeID = 0;
        int parameterStoreID = 0;
        List<int> parameterStoreIDs = null;
        DateTime parameterFromDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime parameterToDate = DateTime.Now;
```

I need to strip the values from the list of report parameters so I can use them in the data population methods. For example, I'm doing something like...

```
int parameterEmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(parameterList[parameterList.FindIndex(x => x.Name == "employeeID")].Values[0]);
```

But then I run into issues on the `List<int> parameterStoreIDs`, because I can't convert a StringCollection to a List of ints.

Does anyone have any recommendations on either a) converting the StringCollection to a list of ints, or b) anything else I could try doing to get the information back from the second form besides a `List<ReportParameters>` ???

Comment: I'm a little confused about (b).  If you aren't passing values through the report down to the data sources, why do you need to pass parameters to the reports at all?  And if you don't, why use `ReportParameter` objects?

Comment: Yeah, I honestly DON'T need to use `ReportParameter` objects, they were just the easiest way to pass back a list of objects that could be lists, ints, strings, or all of the above, all at the same time. I'm trying to find a way to get a collection of random objects from one form, and use those to populate a datasource. ReportParameters were just the first thing I found that could be used to return multiple object types - definitely not attached to them

Comment: How dynamic are your parameters?  Do you think the 30 or so will be all that will be asked for, for a while?  Because I think writing a parameters class that has properties for all the different parameter values (or collections) might be your best bet.  The thing with `ReportParameter` and similar can-be-anything objects/collections is that you have to incorporate the intelligence about what they are and how to use them somewhere.  If you create a custom class you've done it once, up front.

Comment: We're still deciding on it... we're pretty sure that the 30 is all we would ever use, but at the same time I'd like to build in as much future expand-ability as possible. I'll take a look into doing that --- thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question (a), consider something like this:

I am not clear on what variable in the code would be the `StringCollection`, so for the sake of the example I'm just calling it `strings`.

```
List<int> ints = strings.Cast<string>(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, I had tried something like that, but the `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` object doesn't contain any `Convert` or `Cast` type calls. I've got it working by doing a `foreach` loop that iterates through, converts, and spits back a list, but it looks like code I would have written when I first started programming. I mean... if it works it works, but at the same time it's so ugly it makes me want to cry!

Comment: Have you got `System.Linq` in your `using` statements?  `StringCollection` does implement `IEnumerable`, which means that you can use the extension method `Cast<string>` to get an `IEnumerable<string>`.  Once you have that, you can use a lambda to convert to `Int32`, as I do in my answer.  (see the Extension Methods section of this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But if you feel stuck with the ugly routine, you could wrap it in an extension method and call it like this:  `strings.ConvertToIntegerList()`.

Comment: Using your `System.Linq` tip actually got me to get it into the right format! Thanks a ton! Here's what I had to do -> `List<int> parameterStoreIDs = parameterList[parameterList.FindIndex(x => x.Name == "storeIDs")].Values.Cast<int>().ToList();` --- kind of hard to read, but at least it's usable!

Comment: Awesome!  You could even extract that into a separate subroutine to which all you had to pass was the parameter list and the value name!